# TextView and Button same dimensions but showing differently

Tags: android, button, layout, textview

I am creating TextView and Buttons dynamically, but although I give them the same size, they surprisingly show quite differently.

```
RelativeLayout journals = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

layoutUserDoes = new RelativeLayout(this);

layoutUserDoes.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(journals.getWidth() , 100));
layoutUserDoes.setY(0);
layoutUserDoes.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
journals.addView(layoutUserDoes);

TextView t1=new TextView(this);
t1.setTextSize(20);
t1.setText("t1");
t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
t1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
t1.setWidth(50);
t1.setHeight(40);
t1.setX(20);

layoutUserDoes.addView(t1);

Button t2=new Button(this);
t2.setTextSize(20);
t2.setText("t2");
t2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
t2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
t2.setWidth(50);
t2.setHeight(40);
t2.setX(71);

layoutUserDoes.addView(t2);
```

[image]

Comment: it's due to the difference between TextView and Button style check your style in `/res/values/styles.xml`

Comment: I am facing the following problem and maybe I am on the wrong track:
I have a variable number of Buttons and TextViews (stored in an array) to put on the whole width of the screen. And the result should be placed nicely in the middle,  each one directly after the preceeding one. That's why I thought going for pixels. No way I can do that in XML layout.
What would be your suggestions?

Comment: check out this gist : https://gist.github.com/selmanon/eab80e982abc8cead34d

Answer (score 0):

You missed a concept.

When you use

```
t2.setX(71);
```

you are working [with pixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)). But each device has a different density of points. So, in your case, px and dp don't macht.

To solve this you have two options

1.- You can define the buttons statically in a xml file.

2.- You can just write:

```
t2.setX(90);
```

I suggest you the first solution, and if you have time you should read [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

I hope it helps.

Comment: @michaelsmith Did it work? Didn't? Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

set style in your TextView to have the same as the button

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
```